# Is the Canonical Commutation Relation always valid?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, commutator

Is the [canonical commutation relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) $[p,x]=-i\hbar$ always valid?

For example:

I need to calculate the expectation value, $\langle x(t) \rangle$, at all times expressed in the results $x_0$ and $p_0$

I've found that $x_0=\langle x \rangle=\frac{5a}{16}$ and $p_0=\langle p \rangle=-i\hbar\frac{a^4}{2}$ to time $t=0$ with $\Psi(x,0)=N(a^2-x^2)e^{ikx}$ for $|x|\leq a$

$N=\sqrt{\frac{15}{8a^5}}$

To do this I'd use Ehrenfest's theorem, thus

$$\frac{d\langle x \rangle}{dt}=\frac{i}{\hbar}\left\langle[p,x]\right\rangle$$

Would $[p,x]$ equal $-i\hbar$ here?

Comment: $[p,x] = -i\hbar$ is valid when $p$ denotes the generator of spatial translations. Your last line writes the generator of *time* translations (normally denoted $H$) as $p$.

Comment: You're using the Ehrenfest with the Hamiltonian $H=p$, which, in phase space, is just a uniform translation in position. It is therefore consistent with the theorem's result when considering expected values, plugging in the constant value of the commutator.

Comment: @LPZ so [p,x] would be $-i\hbar$ here?

Comment: Yes, you therefore get $$\frac{d}{dx}\langle x\rangle = 1$$ as expected, since $p$ is the (normalised) generator of translations.

Comment: @LPZ Okay, great that is what I get too.
Now my problem is how I express this answer with $x_0$ and $p_0$